# Instantiating Scala Type Members results in error

Tags: scala, type-members

Quick question on why we can't instantiate type members? For example take this example:

```
abstract class SimpleApplicationLoader {
  type MyComponents <: BuiltInComponentsFromContext

  def load(context: Context) = {
    new MyComponents(context).application
  }
}

class SiteServiceApplicationLoader extends SimpleApplicationLoader {
  type MyComponents = SiteApplicationComponents
}

class SiteApplicationComponents(val context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
      ....
}
```

The *SimpleApplicationLoader* defines a type parameter *MyComponents* (upper bound to *BuiltinComponentsFromContext*). In the *load* method, the type parameter *MyComponents* is instantiated. *SiteServiceApplicationLoader* overrides the MyComponents type to _SiteApplicationComponents).

Anyway, the compiler gives the following error:

```
Error:(13, 9) class type required but SimpleApplicationLoader.this.MyComponents found
    new MyComponents(context).application
```

Just curious why *type members* cannot be instantiated? Any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator `new` is only available for [classes (or "like classes")](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions). Type is not a class, so `new` is not available.

To instantiate an arbitrary type, a function could be used

```
def newMyComponents(context: Context): MyComponents
```

**Update (thanks to @daniel-werner)**

So the abstract class will look like

```
abstract class SimpleApplicationLoader {
  type MyComponents <: BuiltInComponentsFromContext

  def newMyComponents(context: Context): MyComponents

  def load(context: Context) = {
    newMyComponents(context).application    
  }
}
```

The abstract method might be implemented in the `class` where `type` is defined:

```
class SiteServiceApplicationLoader extends SimpleApplicationLoader {
  type MyComponents = SiteApplicationComponents
  def newMyComponents(context: Context): MyComponents = 
    new SiteApplicationComponents(context)
}
```

Comment: To clarify: You are suggesting to add an abstract method `newMyComponents` (which returns `MyComponents`) to `SimpleApplicationLoader`. This method will then be implemented in `SiteServiceApplicationLoader`. Is this correct? Because this meaning didn't become 100% clear from the first code example.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot instantiate a type. You can only instantiate a class.

There is nothing in your code that constrains `MyComponents` to be a class. It could just as well be a trait, a singleton type, a compound type, or even an abstract class, which also cannot be instantiated.

Other languages have ways to constrain types to be classes, or have constructors. For example, in C♯, you can constrain a type to be class or struct with a zero-argument constructor. But Scala does not have a feature for such constraints.